# Actionscript and Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to retrieve the network adaptater in use.

Using this code

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html#WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b04a6701d612482d399e5-8000

But for any reason it can find the "import flash.net.InterfaceAddress" "import flash.net" library.

I dont know why.

- Language Version: ActionScript 3.0
- Runtime Versions: AIR 2

see [screen errors](https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-6739523-672991/errors.jpg)

---

I'm using a very recent version of Flash Builder (the latest).

Air SDK came with it.

I found this "airglobal.swc" file at three places.

=> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\frameworks\libs\air
=> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\3.6.0\frameworks\libs\air
=> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\air

My project is a simple "action script project", not a flex one. But I also tried to create a flex project and encountered the same problem

Comment: flash.net resides in the airglobal.swc in the SDK. My advice is to check if your SDK is complete and use one of the newer ones that are available (i.e. Flex 4.6 + AIR 13 or 14 or 15)

Comment: I am using a very recent version of Flash Builder, the latest.
Air SDK came with it.
I found this "airglobal.swc" file at three places.


=> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\frameworks\libs\air 

=> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\3.6.0\frameworks\libs\air
=> C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\air


My project is a simple "action script project", not a flex one. But i also tried to create a flex project and encountered the same prob.

Comment: When you created your project, did you specify "Desktop" under "Application Type"?  If you didn't, the AIR APIs won't be available.

Comment: Brian is most likely correct, have a look at [the Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package-detail.html). The packages you want to import are for AIR projects only, try to create a project for AIR for Desktop in Flash Builder.

Comment: Thank you Brian! It works now...

Does someone know if i can get a list of the network adapters using only AS3(it must work work on a computer without Flex but flashplayer).

Answer (score 0):

That package isn't a native flash builder/air library. Its a flash library but only avail in flash, not flash builder.

To import it into flash builder:

Open Flash, on frame one write this action script:

```
import flash.net.*

var forceImport: InterfaceAddress
```

1. Goto export properties of flash and choose the SWC option.
2. Copy SWC file into your flash builder project.
3. Goto properties of your project choose "flex build path" and then "Add swc".
4. Point to your SWC.

Now flash builder has access to that flash package.